# Should wildcard first character change behaviour of lazy sub?

Tags: python, regex

Why do the following two expressions return different results?

This returns `-` as expected:

```
re.sub(r'\w.*?-', '', 'test--')
```

But this returns the empty string ``, which is surprising to me.

```
re.sub(r'.*?-', '', 'test--')
```

I'm running Python 3.7.

Comment: `re.sub` matches all occurrences and `.*?-` can also match `-`. `\w.*?-` can't match `-`. See https://regex101.com/r/DE0By6/2. Always use regex101 or similar sites to check your patterns.

Comment: Actually I did check. The problem turns out to be that `sub()` matches all occurrences when `count=0`, and the doc says "leftmost non-overlapping occurrences", which I found confusing, especially given that there is also `subn` method.

Comment: True, that sounds confusing. I think the point of using "leftmost" is to stress the fact that the matches are searched for from left to right. Still, "occurrence**s**" means *all* occurrences are found by default.